# PHP MYSQL special characters do not show good

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I have a PHP file encoded with UTF-8 like this :

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

And before using sql request, I've added this line :

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

My database is coded in `UTF-8` and varchar column with `latin_swedish_ci`

The result is like this picture :

[image]

Comment: Try `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">`

Comment: when i use "iso-8859-1" the arabic caracters dont showed good

Comment: Try changing your database to "utf8_general_ci"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Im not sure it matters,but shouldn't utf8 in you query be without quotes

Comment: Thank's Mihai, i've add this property when i instance a PDO object `new PDO('mysql:charset=utf8');`

Answer (score 0):

Chang code to this

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
```

Save file like this

[image: Save file like this]

Comment: it's enconding without BOM

Answer (score 0):

This is due to incorrect collation / charset of your column. Even if your database characted set is `UTF-8`, the column's character set takes precedence. To handle special characters like japanese chinese you column should be set to `utf8_bin` instead of `latin_swedish_ci`

Answer (score 0):

Some Steps to Follow:

Meta tag for UTF8.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Set your PHP to use UTF8.

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
mb_http_input('UTF-8');
```

For MySql, you've to convert your table to UTF8.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Also run:

```
 SET NAMES UTF8
```

as the first query after establishing a connection which will convert your DB connection to UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

html encoding in meta tag gets ignored if it is sent via http headers already.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Check from you browser what it thinks the current page encoding is:

- Chrome: Tools - Encoding
- Firefox: View - Character encoding

MySQL should be ok with just "set names utf8", table dada is encoded automatically to the mysql connections encoding